Simplistic Magnetic Train Physics
This is NOT a question regarding Maglev trains, but rather the simple toy train that one can make at home as seen here.
I have a question regarding the steady state of the system.
Consider an (over)simplified case: An infinitely long straight solenoid, with $n$ turns per unit length, its resistance per unit length is $\lambda$. The radius is the solenoid is $R$. For the engine of the train, consider an ideal cell of no internal resistance, and its EMF is $\mathcal{E}$. Consider two thin magnets of magnetic moment $M$ fixed (or placed) at the end of the cell. We neglect the magnetic susceptibility of the magnets($\chi = 0$). The effective length of the cell and magnets is $l$. Here, I assume the magnets to act like point dipoles(its an approximation, after all).

There now exist a current through the solenoid within the region of the cell. We can find the current through the wire in this region(from A to B).
$$i = \frac{\mathcal{E}}{\text{resistance}} = \frac{\mathcal{E}}{2\pi n \lambda l R}$$
We know that the field due to a solenoid is given by
$$B = \frac{\mu_0 n i}{2} ( \cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2 )$$

Potential energy of a dipole in a magnetic field is given by,
$$U = - \vec{M} \cdot \vec{B}$$
$$\implies \vec{F} = \nabla ( \vec{M} \cdot \vec{B} )$$
For our dipole, we get the angle as $0$ rad, and the magnetic dipole moment is constant, so:
$$F = M \nabla B$$
Hence, we get:
$$F = M \frac{\mu_0 n i}{2} \left( \frac{R^2}{(x^2+R^2)^{3/2}} - \frac{R^2}{(R^2+(l-x)^2)^{3/2}} \right)$$
This is for a single magnet. We place magnets on both sides of the cell. Hence we must add their forces vectorically.
Note, at Pt. A, $x =0$ and at Pt. B, $x =l$.
Hence, we get:
$$F_{\text{net}} = M \mu_0 n i \left( \frac{1}{R} - \frac{R^2}{(R^2+l^2)^{3/2}} \right)$$
Note that we actually do $| \vec{F}_A | - | \vec{F}_B |$ to get this, otherwise we get $F$ as zero. This basically implies that the magnets must face each other as shown in the diagram.
Till here, I've understood everything. Now, the questions:

This is a constant force. There is no retardation for the cell. It should accelerate infinitely(in this model). I know we neglect friction. So, is friction the only thing that causes it to slow down? And if so, what expression should I use for friction to get a more accurate model, with the given approximations and assumptions.
Experimentally, we get a constant value for velocity of the cell after a while, which is not what we get in this expression. One source that I saw here states that Lenz' law would apply the necessary retarding force till the forces balance out. But when I tried to find it force by electromagnetic induction, I got zero, i.e. the forces from the left of the cell and the right of the cell cancelled each other. No other source(that I visited) mentioned Lenz law. How do we get the constant steady state value of velocity for the train?

I would appreciate answers with some formulae or expressions, not just the theory.
